# AMP: How can I change background color of amp-accordion header?

Tags: background-color, amp-html

I am trying to change the background color of the header in amp-accordion. The only way I have been able to do this is to apply a style to `.-amp-accordion-header` which is invalid.

Answer (score 5):

The AMP validator raises an error if you try to override the classes `.-amp-xxxxx` as suggested in the other answer.

I fixed that issue by creating my own class:

```
.myheader {
    background-color:yellow; 
}
```

and I added that class to the header:

```
<amp-accordion>
    <section expanded>
        <h2 class="myheader">Section 1</h2>
        <p>Bunch of awesome content</p>
    </section>
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right with changing it in `.-amp-accordion-header`. Maybe you missed something with your code. Here is an [example from GitHub](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/1849/files):

```
/* heading element*/
.-amp-accordion-header {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #dfdfdf;
}
```